# Why are no functions detected after upgrading to dotnet-isolated in my azure functions app

Tags: .net, azure-functions

I'm trying to deploy an app that needs .net 5 functionality and thus dotnet-isolated. However after changing my `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` setting to `dotnet-isolated`, adding the appropriate dependencies and program.cs, and publishing a hello world app, no functions are detected on app load. What could be causing this to happen

Comment: Just change it to `dotnet-isolated` is not enough, please follow [this article](https://daveabrock.com/2021/02/24/functions-dotnet-5) about how to upgrade to .net 5 function. Note, if you don't need EF / middleware, then just ignore these related sections in the above article.

Comment: Yes I've done all that as well, will update my question

Comment: can you run it successfully locally before publish it? and as of now, the tools like visual studio is not supported as well, I suggest you should use function core tools to run and publish it, see [this article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker#create-and-run-net-isolated-functions).

Comment: Yes I'm able to run it locally. I will attempt to deploy via  the commandline

Comment: cool!. Please let me know if there is any further issue:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the visual studio and other tools are not supported well for function `.net 5.0`, I suggest you should use `Azure Functions Core Tools` to publish the azure function `.net 5.0`.

You can upgrade the existing azure function to .net 5.0 via visual studio as per [this doc](https://daveabrock.com/2021/02/24/functions-dotnet-5)(Or you can directly create a .net 5.0 function via [this link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker#create-and-run-net-isolated-functions), and then modify your existing function by comparing that one).

After upgrading, run it locally to make sure it can work well. Then use the code below(it's `Azure Functions Core Tools`) to create a function service:

```
az functionapp create --resource-group AzureFunctionsQuickstart-rg --consumption-plan-location westeurope --runtime dotnet-isolated --functions-version 3 --name <APP_NAME> --storage-account <STORAGE_NAME>
```

Then publish it via this command:

```
func azure functionapp publish <APP_NAME>
```

For more details, please refer to [the official doc](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker#create-and-run-net-isolated-functions).

I upgraded my existing azure function 3.1 to .net 5.0 as per steps above, and it can be published to azure portal successfully.

Please let me know if you still have more issues about it.

Comment: Publishing from the command line seems to fix the problem

Comment: This is a horrible answer, it basically means there's no longer a way to run locally with VS and debug functions any more if this is the "best way forward".

Comment: @War your misunderstanding this answer. The OP **can** run it locally but can't run it in Azure. This is fixing that issue. It has nothing to do with *run locally with VS and debug functions*